# Como fazer um "procv" no Python utilizando a biblioteca Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, procv

boa tarde!

Tenho o csv abaixo:

```
Nome      Vendas      Produto       Data
Carlos     83,40       cod2       15/04/2020
Andre      70,50       cod5       10/04/2020
Cristina    100        cod7       25/04/2020
Carlos     20,80       cod1       03/04/2020
Gisele     10,50       cod9       11/04/2020
Andre      33,70       cod6       30/04/2020
```

Coloquei somente um pedaço para exemplo e demonstrar minha ideia.

Preciso que fique da seguinte maneira:
Que as colunas fiquem com os nomes e abaixo de cada nome o valor das vendas.

```
Carlos  Andre  Cristina  Gisele
83,40   70,50   100       10,50
20,80   33,70
```

Bom, o primeiro passo foi tentar montar essa estrutura.
Usei o código abaixo:

```
import pandas as pd
import codecs

arquivo = pd.read_csv(codecs.open("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Python\\relatorio.csv", "rU", "ansi"),sep=';',infer_datetime_format=True, index_col=False)
arquivo.columns = ['Nome','Vendas']

Nomes = arquivo[['Nome']]
Nomes = Nomes.drop_duplicates(subset = ['Nome'])
Nomes = Nomes.reset_index()

Nomes_drop = Nomes.drop(columns = ['index'])
Nomes_Colunas = Nomes_drop.T.reset_index()
```

Agora não tenho ideia de como fazer esse "procv" para trazer as informações de venda para as respectivas colunas.
Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podemos fazer um [unstack](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) após um [GroupBy](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

```
df.groupby('Nome')['Vendas'].apply(lambda df: df.reset_index(drop=True)).unstack(0)
```

Comment: Muito grato, deu certo.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode agrupar por nome para juntar as vedas de cada pessoa e depois iterar nos grupos para pegar os dados. A partir disso construir um novo dataframe.

vendas.txt File

```
Nome,Vendas,Produto,Data
Carlos,83.40,cod2,15/04/2020
Andre,70.50,cod5,10/04/2020
Cristina,100,cod7,25/04/2020
Carlos,20.80,cod1,03/04/2020
Gisele,10.50,cod9,11/04/2020
Andre,33.70,cod6,30/04/2020
```

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("vendas.csv")
# Vamos manter apenas as colunas "Nome" e "Vendas"
df = df[["Nome", "Vendas"]]

# Vamos agrupar por nome
grouped = df.groupby("Nome")

# Número de vendas -> Vai ser o número de linhas do dataframe final
num_vendas = grouped.count().max()[0]


def to_list_fixed_size(series, size):
    """
    Converte `series` para uma lista e se o tamanho dessa lista for menor que
    `size`, adiciona tantos elementos `None` quanto necessário.
    """
    l = list(series)
    if len(l) < size:
        l.extend([None] * (size - len(l)))
    return l

# Cada chave no dicionário corresponde ao nome de um vendedor e o valor
# associado é uma lista com as vendas. A função "to_list_fixed_size" definida
# antes garante que as listas com as vendas de todos os vendedores possua o
# mesmo tamanho para que possamos criar um dataframe depois com esse dicionário.
data = {i: to_list_fixed_size(j.Vendas, num_vendas) for i,j in grouped}

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

O DataFrame final fica como abaixo

```
   Andre  Carlos  Cristina  Gisele
0   70.5    83.4     100.0    10.5
1   33.7    20.8       NaN     NaN
```